# SQL Query multiple tables same values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I'm having an issue creating a query. Here are the specifics.

1. There are 2 tables company_career and company_people.
2. People contains person information (Name, Address, etc) and Career contains historical career information (job_title, department, etc.)
3. People is linked to Career by job_ref_id.
4. Direct_Report_id lies in the career table and contains a unique id that correlates to job_ref_id.

Example: job_ref_id = '1' results in direct_report_id ='A'. I then use the value produced  from direct-report_id (i.e., 'A') and query the job_ref_id = 'A' and this produces the employee name. Since it produces the employee name (which is actually the manager) I need to know how I would query this to present this as the manager name.

Comment: Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: There is nothing specific here.. all seems to be speculations... be specific with sample data

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are looking for, you just need to use joins and aliases. For example:

```
SELECT
cp.name AS [EmployeeName],
cp.address AS [EmployeeAddress],
cc.job_title AS [EmployeeTitle],
cc.department AS [EmployeeDept],
m.name AS [ManagerName]
FROM company_people cp
LEFT JOIN company_career cc ON cc.job_ref_id = cp.job_ref_id
LEFT JOIN company_people m ON m.job_ref_id = cc.direct_report_id
```